# Continuity of $\cos(\sqrt{z})$ (and $\sin(\sqrt{z})$) in $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've only seen what I consider a weak argument for these.
The weak argument relies on $\cos(\sqrt{z})$ being even (therefore it's continuous in the plane) and $\sin(\sqrt{z})$ odd (therefore it's not continuous on the negative reals, nor imaginary).

But, what is the more rigorous argument for the continuity/discontinuity of $\cos(\sqrt{z})$ (and $\sin(\sqrt{z})$) in $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Your functions are **not** even/odd, we have $\cos(\sqrt{-1}) = \cosh(1)\ne \cos(1)$ and $\sin(\sqrt{-1})=i \sinh(1)$ is purely imaginary!

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Note that the functions $\cos z$ and $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ are even:
$$\cos z = \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!} \\
\frac{\sin z}{z} = \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
hence 
$$\cos( \sqrt{z}) =  \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n\frac{z^n}{(2n)!} \\
\sin (\sqrt{ z})= \sqrt{z} \cdot \sum_{n\ge 0} (-1)^n\frac{z^{n}}{(2n+1)!}$$
The function $\cos( \sqrt{z})$ is an honest holomorphic functions, while $\sin(\sqrt{z})$ will be multivalued, like $\sqrt{z}$.